How to setup the Protocol handler for SSH in Ubuntu 24.04
I have applications that give me a ssh:// command from browsers and other applications. I'm new to the Linux world and learning, but have not found anything that would allow me to do this. In Windows and MacOS systems, the ssh:// is a default file type and then opens a third party app on the system. When I try this on my Ubuntu desktop I get errors like 'Unable to activate the system protocol handler for ssh://'
Is it possible to do this in Ubuntu 24 Desktop?
I tried a very old script and post from Cisco but it does not appear to have been maintained in many years and didn't do anything for me. Thoughts on setting up the protocol handler for SSH on Ubuntu Desktop 24?
